# PDF not showing in a WebView

Tags: android, firebase, android-webview

I have an App in which I want to show a PDF file in a WebView.
I have tried to do this

```
webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        progressbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
        String filename =**"My Firebase PDF Url"**;
        webview.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + filename);

webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
   public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
           progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
   });
}
```

But when I run the App it shows a white screen. Does anybody know what's wrong?
I am using a PDF download URL from firebase as **"My Firebase PDF Url"**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

```
String pdf = "https://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf";
            wvPDF.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

            wvPDF.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + pdf);

            wvPDF.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                }
            });
```

Its working for me, Please make sure you have Internet permission and use https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=

Comment: Thanks but When I do this, it now says "no preview available"

Comment: Its working for me. I have attached screenshot as well.

Comment: When I use your URL, it loads just fine. Guess the problem is with my firebase URL. Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: @Tech1 the problem with your case is that the firebase url does not contains **.pdf** at the end. Like in the answer the url contains **.pdf** at the end. So either you can host your pdf's directly on hosting websites or github pages. You must not use drive or firebase based pdf link for showing pdf's in webview.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these settings to webview,

```
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webview.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void downloadPdfFromInternet(String url, final String dirPath, final String fileName) {
    PRDownloader.download(
            url,
            dirPath,
            fileName
    ).build().start(new OnDownloadListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDownloadComplete() {
            File downloadedFile = new File(dirPath, fileName);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            showPdfFromFile(downloadedFile);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Error error) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext,
                    "Error in downloading file : $error",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });


    PRDownloader.download(
            url,
            dirPath,
            fileName
    ).build();

}

private void showPdfFromFile(File file) {
    pdfView.fromFile(file)
            .password(null)
            .defaultPage(0)
            .enableSwipe(true)
            .swipeHorizontal(false)
            .enableDoubletap(true)
            .load();
}
```

As Android Decline PDF view from webview, so you can prefer this link

https://github.com/eduxcellence/PDFViewer/find/master